# Will or will not sum always equals sum of averages after being rounded up?

Tags: calculus

Let's say we have $n$ values $x_1, x_2,..., x_n$ and their average $\bar{x}$.

My question is: given $x_i$ and $\bar{x}$ have **4** (or $m$) decimal places, will $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ always equal $\bar{x} * n$ if both of them are rounded to **3** (or $m - 1$) decimal places or less? Is it provable if yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let's take more than $10$ values so that the absolute error can grow by at least one order of magnitude. For instance, take $n=100$ values, out of which $51$ will be $0$ and $49$ will be $0.0001$. Now $\overline{x}=0.0049/100=0.000049\approx 0$ to $4$ decimals. Note now $\sum x_i=0.0049\approx 0.005$ to $3$ decimals, but $n\overline{x}=0$.

The bottom line is: by multiplying $n\overline{x}$ you magnified the rounding error of $\overline{x}$ by the factor $n$, so even if the error previously was smaller than $0.5\cdot 10^{-m}$ it can grow bigger than $0.5\cdot 10^{-(m-1)}$